# plot_model() resize between axis and label space

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

May I ask how can I resize the space between the axis and label, things gonna worse after I set the axis.labels(), I prefer the label has a soft position (not wrapping) like the pic2.

> pic1 code (wrapping not like it):

```
 plot_model(X1, type = "est", axis.lim = c(0.1,5),show.values = TRUE, show.intercept = T, value.offset = .3,colors = c("blue","red"))
```

> pic2 code (want the text not wrapping):

```
plot_model(X2, type = "est", axis.lim = c(0.1,5),show.values = TRUE,  show.intercept = T, value.offset = .3,colors = c("blue","red"),
  axis.labels=rev(c("(Intercept)", "Group (OT)", "S_O (Self)", "Block", "Hierarchy1st (Superior)" ,"Hierarchy1st (Inferior)" ,
   "Group (OT) × S_O (Self)" , "Group (OT) × Block" , "S_O (Self) × Block", "Block × Hierarchy1st (Superior)", "Block × Hierarchy1st (Inferior)" ,"S_O (Self) × Block × Hierarchy1st (Superior)" ,"S_O (Self) × Block × Hierarchy1st (Inferior)" )))
```

Thanks a lot!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi OP, can you please share some additional information?  For example, include code and datasets or example datasets so that we have a minimal reproducible example.  Additionally, can you clarify what you mean by "soft position"?  The difference I see is that the first picture has text wrapping on the axis text and the second picture does not.

Comment: yes, I will put the code, and soft position= not wrapping~

Comment: with your inspiration, I find the wrap.lables() ! thanks a lot!